# netstat command doesnt work anymore on the new dedicated server

Tags: compatibility, freebsd, netstat

I was using the following command on my previous dedicated server with the same version of the FreeBSD installation:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013     root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

The command is following:

```
netstat -ntu -f inet
```

Output:

```
netstat: illegal option -- t
```

Why doesn't it work anymore? I dont have an access to my previous dedicated server so I can't use the `man` to check the differences...

Answer (score 0):

You can check man on the [freebsd website](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi)

in short review i see that -t was removed in 9.X branch for [some reasons](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=199992)